# python multithreading how member function of threads call functions outside class

Tags: python, multithreading

I read the example code following. What I wonder this how member function of myThread, run can call function defined outside class, myThread.
Is it normal to code in this way when using multithreading?

```
import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        print_time(self.name, 5, self.counter)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def print_time(threadName, counter, delay):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
        threadName.exit()
    time.sleep(delay)
    print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
    counter -= 1

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: Threads run in the same memory space, so they will have access to all the same objects as the main thread including function objects. If you were to use `multiprocessing`, memory is not shared, and the child process would get access to the function `print_time` by `import *`ing the entire file. This is why when using processes, you need to use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` construct to separate the code out you only want to run in the main thread (and not when it's imported).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with multithreading. You can easily come up with an example of class methods calling functions outside of the class

```
def func():
    # something

class A:
    def method(self):
        func()
```

In python, when you call a function, it will search for that name. Since you declared(defined) the function in global namespace(by `def func()`), it finds it and executes it. That's just some normal python behavior which has nothing to do with multithreading.

However, when it comes to whether it's normal to code this way, it depends. It's not a horrible thing to have a "global" function which you can call from anywhere in this file. Actually that's how C works. But if you want your code to be more "object-oriented", you should probably put this function in some class and use it from there. That's really a design issue, or maybe a coding style discussion.

Answer (score 0):

after assigning the thread a function to execute, it will wait to be manually started, so thread1.start() means --> you can start now and you can do your job.

def run(self):

```
print "Starting " + self.name
print_time(self.name, 5, self.counter)
print "Exiting " + self.name
```

Code to execute when the thread is starting.